# Can I use an allocator object to free memory allocated by another allocator?

Tags: c++, allocator

As far as I know, `std::allocator` is introduced by the library to allocate uninitialized unconstructed blocks of memory. So:

```
std::allocator<int> a;
auto ptr = a.allocate(100);
auto e = ptr;
while (e != ptr + 5)
    a.construct(e++, 0);

for (auto tmp = ptr; tmp != e; )
    std::cout << *tmp++ << ", ";
std::cout << std::endl;

std::allocator<int> a2;
std::allocator<int> a3 = a;

for (auto tmp = ptr; tmp != e; )
    a.destroy(tmp++);

//for (auto tmp = ptr; tmp != e; )
//  a2.destroy(tmp++); // is it UB using a2 here to destroy elements?

//for (auto tmp = ptr; tmp != e; )
//  a3.destroy(tmp++); // is it UB also?

a.deallocate(ptr, 100); // ok
//a2.deallocate(ptr, 100); // UB or OK?
//a3.deallocate(ptr, 100); // UB or ok?
```

- What I am not sure about is whether using another allocator `a2`, `a3` objects (one of them) to free (deallocate) memory allocated by `a` is Undefined Behavior?
- If it is OK why classes like `std::vector` has an allocator object and not just create a temporary one to alloc/dealloc memory?

Please clarify the questions above.

Comment: @walnut: That is off the topic. consider I comment out those lines and let only one allocator works.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Yes. Nathan. I want to know whether I can use `a2` or `a3` to free memory allocated and constructed by allocator `a`?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Haha how could you spot that mistake?

Comment: It was the only way to make your second question make sense to me ;)

Comment: @NathanOliver: Yea too pedantic about it. you da man!

Comment: Note: `std::allocator` is one type of allocator. There are other types of allocators. This is relevant to the answer.

Answer (score 8):

My reading of the standard says this is undefined behavior, unless the allocators compare equal.  [Table 34: Cpp17Allocator requirements [tab:cpp17.allocator]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/allocator.requirements#tab:cpp17.allocator) states for

> ```
> a.deallocate(p,n)
> ```

that

> Requires: `p` shall be a value returned by an earlier call to `allocate` that has not been invalidated by an intervening call to `deallocate`. `n` shall match the value passed to `allocate` to obtain this memory.

Where `a` is an lvalue of the allocator type.  Since `allocate` is a member function I interpret the use of `allocate` in the quoted text to mean `a.allocate` which would mean you need the same or equal object to deallocate what was allocated.

---

This of course means that something like `vector` couldn't make a temporary when it needed and would need to keep the allocator as a member.

Comment: `std::allocator` instances always compare equal, see https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/default.allocator#allocator.globals-1

Answer (score 7):

You can read about the specification for allocators here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator. They have changed a bit in different standard versions, but I will write about the C++17 and 20 renditions.

When you allocate memory with an allocator `a1`, it can only be deallocated by a different allocator `a2` if `a1 == a2`.  [Quote from the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/allocator.requirements#2.sentence-121):

> `a1 == a2`
>   returns `true` only if storage allocated from each can be deallocated via the other.

`std::allocator<T>` is usually implemented as an empty type with no state. [`std::allocator<T>::is_always_equal::value`](http://eel.is/c++draft/default.allocator#lib:operator=,allocator) is `true`, so all `std::allocator<T>` objects are equal. Thus, both deallocations are well defined.

If it was a stateful allocator, after `AllocatorT a3 = a1`, `a1 == a3` should be `true`, so you are safe to deallocate with it. `AllocatorT a2;` default constructs it, and `a2 == a1` is *probably not* true, so you can't deallocate with `a2`.

In C++17, you could also do `AllocatorT a3 = std::move(a1);`. This means that you could no longer deallocate with `a1` (Unless `a1 == a3` after the move), but only with `a3`. This was changed in C++20, so you can only copy allocators.

Currently, most container implementations contain an object that inherits from the allocator so that if it is empty, [empty base optimisation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo) is used so that it doesn't take any extra bytes. So even if all objects are always the same, it doesn't hurt to use 0 extra bytes to store an allocator (And if it is stateful, an object needs to be stored anyway to deallocate). In C++20, this will probably be implemented with the [`[[no_unique_address]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address) attribute for the same effect.